# Why "Call to a member function on a non-object" in plugin only?

Tags: plugins, php, fatal-error

I am embarking on converting my PHP script, which calls a news search API to pull down news stories, in to a WordPress plugin.
It's early days, I only really have the plugin header so far. I will strip out print_r echos later.

When I activate the plugin, the top of the page returns:

> Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error
>
> Starting... Initialising array and object... Polling API...
> Fatal error: Call to a member function listStories() on a non-object in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-content/plugins/cxt-user-quotes/cxt-user-quotes.php on line 43

Line 43 is `$result = $api_instance->listStories($opts);`

The API code is included with `require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');`

Is it failing to see the `listStories` function from the API file? Is it that `$result` or `$api_instance` need to be initialised?

Important to note that the code works fine when executed through PHP on the command line - `php myscript.php` - just not within the WordPress plugin.

Possibly related - what should I know about hooks and actions in this regard? Maybe this has something to do with execution order?

The `while(true)` loop at the bottom means that this would call the function `fetch_new_stories` on an infinite loop at 60-second intervals.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: News Monitor
 * Description: Finds and ingests citations from news media.
 * Version: 1.0.0
 */



 require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');




 // Fetch new stories

 function fetch_new_stories($opts){

    // print_r("-----------\n");

   global $api_instance;

   print_r("Initialising array and object...\n\n");
   // Initialise array
   $fetched_stories = [];
   // Initialise object
   $stories = NULL;

   // Whether $stories is empty or not
   while (is_null($stories) || count($stories) > 0) {
     try {
       // Poll the API's Stories (listStories) endpoint and get result
       print_r("Polling API...\n\n");
       $result = $api_instance->listStories($opts);
       // For each story (addition from standard Aylien code)
       for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($result->getStories()); $i++){
         // Echo the headline
         print_r($result->getStories()[$i]->getSource()->getName() . ": " . $result->getStories()[$i]->getTitle() . "\n\n");
       }
     }
       // Error handling
       catch (Exception $e) {
       // Get status code
       $code = $e->getResponseObject()->getErrors()[0]->getStatus();
       // Slow down
       if ($code == '429'){
         print_r("Usage limit are exceeded. Wating for 60 seconds...\n");
         sleep(60);
         continue;
   }
 }

     // Get all "stories" from the query result
     $stories = $result->getStories();
     // Add each story sequentially in to $fetched_stories array
     $fetched_stories = array_merge($fetched_stories, $stories);
     // Pagination stuff
     $opts['cursor'] = $result->getNextPageCursor();

     // Count both new stories from this query and total stories
     // print_r(sprintf("Fetched %d stories. Total story count so far: %d\n", count($stories), count($fetched_stories)));
     print_r(sprintf("Fetched %d stories.\n\n", count($stories)));
   }

   // Pass fetched stories
   return $fetched_stories;
 }




 // Configure API key authorization: app_id
 Aylien\NewsApi\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setApiKey('X-AYLIEN-NewsAPI-Application-ID', 'xxxxxxxx');

 // Configure API key authorization: app_key
 Aylien\NewsApi\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setApiKey('X-AYLIEN-NewsAPI-Application-Key', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

 $api_instance = new Aylien\NewsApi\Api\DefaultApi();





 // Query
 $params = array(
   'title' => 'Trump',
   'published_at_start' => 'NOW-1HOUR',
   'published_at_end' => 'NOW',
   'language' => ['en'],
   'per_page' => 50,
   'sort_by' => 'published_at',
   'sort_direction' => 'desc'
 );






 // Infinite loop

 while(true){

    // For each WordPress user {

        print_r("Starting...\n");

        // Fetch new stories from function
        $stories = fetch_new_stories($params);

        print_r("************\n\n");
        // Count stories published during window
        print_r(sprintf("Summary:\n\nPeriod %s to %s: Fetched %d stories\n", $params['published_at_start'], $params['published_at_end'], count($stories)));

        if (count($stories) > 0){
            // Add 10 seconds to last fetched time
            $lastFetchedAt = $stories[0]->getPublishedAt()->add(new DateInterval('PT10S'));

            $params['cursor'] = '*';
            $params['published_at_start'] = $lastFetchedAt->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
    }

        print_r("Sleeping for 60 seconds until next poll...\n\n");
        print_r("************\n\n");
        // print_r("-----------\n\n");

        sleep(60);

    // }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: I figured out that I needed to place the `while(true)` loop, and the API query $params, inside a function and hook that for WordPress to execute it, am I right? So I did `function infinite_loop()` and `add_action( 'init', 'infinite_loop' );` This makes `listStories()` okay - I successfully saw the plugin echo API results in the back-end. This prompts a bigger question - is it wise to put this on a 60-second infinite loop inside the plugin? Does this then get executed on every page load? I just want it left running in the background, once. Should I use a cron or is there an attractive method?